# Sequelize query inside then()

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, sequelize.js

Trying to:

1. get a list of users
2. from the user details get the trips created by the users
3. and based on the output performing some actions

The following is the code I am trying to run.

```js
models.user.findAll({})
    .then(function (users) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var userName = users[i].name;
            var userEmail = users[i].email;

            models.trip.findOne({ attributes: [ [userName, 'name'], [userEmail, 'email'], 'id' ], where: { userId: users[i].id } })
                .then(function (trip) {
                    if (trip == null) {
                        //Send Emails
                    }
                });
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error){ // enter code here
        console.log(">>>>>",error);
    });
```

Due to call back the second Sequelize does not run correctly.

Can you please advice on how to approach this issue? Is it using asyncawait/coyield?

Answer (score 0):

You should debug this by using console.log for example. First you should try to print your first callback result, may be the database connection is not properly configured, may be the table is empty. there are many reasons. also it's more comfortably to use .forEach method instead of 'for' loop

```
array.forEach((item, i, arr)=>{
    ///....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the async method in for and any loop. It is better to use [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com) or any async library.
The code will be like that.

```
var tasks = []
users.forEach(function (user) {
    tasks.push(models.trip({/*some attrs*/}).then(function (trip){
        if (trip) return Promise.resolve()
        return sendEmailPromise(user)
    }))
})
Promise.all(tasks).then(function() {
    //done
}).catch(errorHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the models had associations, such that you could just include the other model and add where clause to it.
[Sequelize Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

```
 User.hasMany(Trips, {foreignKey: 'userId'});

 User.findAll({
   include: {
     model: Trips,
     where: {userId: id}
   }
 });
```